# По ошибке создал проэкт на codepen. Тестировал что и как по этому сервису для разработки. Как его удалить?

Tags: html, css, css3

По ошибке создал проэкт на codepen. Как его удалить, подскажите ? .
Нашел этот проект, нажимаю удалить, у меня переуточняет, хочу ли я удалить, в строку пишу Delete, но кнопка удалить не активна. Как удалить? Скрин прилагаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 'type the words "delete project" to delete your project ->(перевод) впишите слова "delete project" для удаления проекта'.  А на скрине у вас вписано просто "delete"

Answer (score 1):

Тебе надо написать delete project